# how to access the Django view with the @login_required decorator?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am puzzled as to how to access the view associated with  `login_required` decorator. I am trying to use the `requests` library.

Here is the relevant code:

view:

```
@login_required
def user_list(request):
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    serializer = ContactSerializer(users)
        
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls:

```
path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
path('users/', views.user_list, name='user_list')
```

settings:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

For example, I am trying to access the view like this right now and I can't do it:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url,
            auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

where `user` and `pass` are the username and password respectively. And where url is: `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/'`
I get the following error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[11/Jan/2023 04:24:11] "GET /api/users/ HTTP/1.1" 500 71617
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The error is related to login url. you have to add login url in urls.py

```
path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
path('users/', views.user_list, name='user_list'),
path('login/', views.login, name='login')
```

Comment: I still get the same error